# Problems with asynchrony of loading images (using a canvas and timer)

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

[enter link description here](http://www.informedmotion.co.uk/Scripts/jpg.js)I have seen derivatives of the question I am about to ask here but do not think it addresses my problem.

I have a canvas object and I am refreshing it as often as need be.  Sometimes many frames a second.

To get these new frames I call a web api within a recurring timer to get the latest time stamp of a the image on my server and if different loads a hidden canvas object with this data.

When loaded it then 'refreshes' the visible canvas.

On observation I have seen that the images can load up out of sync. I have tested the order the images are sent to my server and I have tested the order the images are 'grabbed' from the server and displayed in the client browser.

How can I ensure that my initial image has finished loading before loading or skipping the next image?

should I use a queue of canvas images and 'read' from the top 1?  Will this cause a memory spike as I have also read that using queue in JavaScript can cause a memory leak?

Thanks

This is my JavaScript code:

I have misnised it by not inclduing the HTML5  and the error handling.

If this is not enough then I post the rest...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var j1 = new JpegImage();

    j1.onload = function () {
        var d1 = ctx1.getImageData(0, 0, 360, 238);
        j1.copyToImageData(d1);
        //BrightenAndContrastImage(d1, contrastBy, brightenBy);
        cSingle.putImageData(d1, 0, 0)
    };

    var tmrFeeder;
    function StartFeedUp() {
        try {
            var throttled = _.delay(StartNonHTML5Feed, 100);
        }
        catch (err) {
            document.getElementById("divMode2").innerHTML = err;
        }
    }


    function StartNonHTML5Feed() {
        jQuery(function ($) {
            jQuery.support.cors = true;
            $.ajax({
                crossDomain: true,
                type: "POST",
                url: "Feed.aspx/GetNextFrames",
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    alias: alias,
                    guidlogon: guidlogon
                }),
                timeout: 10000,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    var ts1 = msg.d['Ts1'];           

                    if (ts1 == "") {
                        ts1 = "0";
                    }

                    if (t1 != ts1) {
                        t1 = ts1;
                        j1.load('/Cloud/LiveXP.ashx?alias=' + alias + '&camindex=0&guid=' + ts1);
                    }
                });
        });
        var throttled = _.delay(StartNonHTML5Feed, 100);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: That's not an issue of using multiple canvases, that just an issue with the asynchrony of loading images. Show us your code!

Comment: "*I have also read that using queue in JavaScript can cause a memory leak?*" - uh, what? Where did you read that? This statement is far too generic too be correct.

Comment: hi Bergi, thanks for correcting me. I will post my code in a second as soon as I finished formatting it.

Comment: @the queue thing.. i will find that source for you as soon as I done the code. BTG, should I change the title of my question now do you think?

Comment: Yeah, adapting the title along with the question would help. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post what `JpegImage` is (and what its `load` function does)?

Comment: I will as soon as I get back (90mins) :)

Comment: hi,  I have added the link to jpg.js

Comment: This seems to be a sync issue. Please let us know your policy about frames (play-them-all / drop-older-ones / ...). And could you please ease our task by emphasizing the id (=frame count) of the image in your code ?

Comment: My bet is you need to implement a priority queue, with the policy you decided. Main method is add(image, frameIndex), which, for instance, would do nothing if frameIndex<lastPlayedFrameIndex, or push the image otherwise. Not sure i'm clear here. Let me know if you want further explanations.

Comment: @GameAlchemist Hi, thanks for your response. The Id is the timestamp in yyyymmddhhmmssfff format.  What I think s haooening is that as I am using a timer an dif the FPS is higher than average that ImageA has not finished loading before ImageB etc. So, yes, i understand what you are suggesting. I would probably drop frames/skip if the duration of the timestamp exceeds 'x' amount of seconds.  I will need a queue system. I will report back :)